# CSS background image. Position on the text

Tags: html, css

Im not sure if this is possible.

I have a background image of a star for some text, it sits at the bottom left of the container. See the below image:
[image]

But when it is viewed on mobile the star is still bottom left..

[image]

Is there a way to position it over the bottom left area of text to create the same wrapping effect? Like this:

[image]

Comment: Sure, use `position: absolute` and adjust position with media query.

Comment: Using `@media` is a good way to specify special styles for smaller windows (mobile devices) just for things like this. The styles specified in the media will only be applied when the window is within the provided threshold.

Comment: can u share your code??

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment, media query and position is a feasible solution:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.star {
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .star {
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        /* bottom: 0; */ /* if it goes at the bottom, up to you homie */
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a style that is used over numerous sections of text, positioning it 50% may not always work as there could be more text in different areas. It needs to be positioned in relation to the bottom left letter if possible

Comment: yes you will have to finick the positioning because you are using these images. It is 50% relative to the container, so you can play with that how you like.